# Do you NEED BIND running next to Apache on a production env (apache is using virtualhosts)?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

Good afternoon to you all. My question is perhaps a simple one. Say I have a webserver running (Linux + Apache) I have a few domains I'd like to point to this machine. all great and dandy BUT! Do I need a dns server like BIND to be running as well? or can I just host multiple websites using just apache and the virtual hosts? thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

There's no requirement to have nameserver software running on your web servers, or running your own nameservers at all for that matter.

However, assuming you have domain names associated with these web sites, you will need nameservers somewhere (quite often a service provided by a different party) to host the relevant zone data.

Comment: Agreed. It's worth mentioning that, unless you have very specific technical reason to host your own DNS, just use a third party. They'll likely do a much better job at hosting your DNS zones than you possibly could do.

Comment: alright understood, I juse use the nameservers that are already filled in on my domain then

Comment: Correct. No requirement for running your own nameservers, although if you are going to be hosting loads and loads of domains it may be beneficial to have your own nameservers somewhere. Most small set ups just use the DNS of the domain registrar or other paid DNS service.

If you do want to set up your own DNS, look into creating a BIND cluster, with a master and slave server. I highly recommend Virtualmin / Webmin for managing that set up. cPanel DNSOnly is another one but I can't remember if you have to have a full cPanel box to use it next to.